# The name "Y" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions are constants constant expressions

Tags: sql

```
CREATE TABLE staff 
(
    address_id integer NOT NULL,
    mobile varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    job_title_id integer NOT NULL,
    is_active char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT Y,
    CONSTRAINT staff_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)  
)
```

Comment: `is_active char(1)  NOT NULL DEFAULT ('Y')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Y needs to be enclosed in quote marks